# Material UI Stepper use state and link function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uistepper

I have been using the material UI stepper as the navigation between different pages in my React project. The pages should change according to the current useState on the stepper, however, it seems to default back to the homepage.

```
function getSteps() {
  return ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'];
}

  function getStepContent(step: number) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return "/page1"
      case 1:
        return "/page2"
      case 2:
        return "/page3"
      case 3:
        return "/page4"
      default:
        return "/page1"
    }
}
```

`already linked to router`

```
export default function HorizontalNonLinearStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('')
  const steps = getSteps();

  const handleStep = (step: number) => () => {
    setActiveStep(step);
    const currentUrl = getStepContent(step)
    setUrl(currentUrl)
    console.log(step)
    console.log(currentUrl)
  };
 
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
    {/*getStepContent(activeStep)*/}
      <Stepper nonLinear activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper}>
        {steps.map((label, index) =>  (
          <Step key={label}>
           <StepButton onClick={handleStep(index)}>
             <Link to = {url}>
            <StepLabel 
              classes={{ label: classes.label, active: classes.labelActive}}
              StepIconProps={{
                classes: { root: classes.icon, text: classes.iconText, active: classes.iconActive},
                }}>
              {label}
              </StepLabel>
              </Link>
            </StepButton>
          </Step> 
        ))}
      </Stepper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT Partial Solution**
This now links the different pages on the stepper component based on the stepper usestate(steps). However, there are now two issues.

1. The user has to click the stepper number to change the use state before clicking the text to change the page.

[image: see image reference]

2. When the new page loads, the stepper use state defaults back to the set useState in the constant below

```
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your main `BrowserRouter`?